# Postgres: Inner Join with AND condition on same field

Tags: sql, postgresql

One `Quiz` can have many `Submissions`. I want to fetch all `Quizzes` that have at least one associated `Submission` with `submissions.correct = t` and at least one associated `Submission` with `submissions.correct = f`.

How can I fix the following query and the WHERE statement in particular to make that happen:

```
SELECT quizzes.*,
       Count(submissions.id) AS submissions_count
FROM   "quizzes"
       INNER JOIN "submissions"
               ON "submissions"."quiz_id" = "quizzes"."id"
WHERE  ( submissions.correct = 'f' )
       AND ( submissions.correct = 't' )
GROUP  BY quizzes.id
ORDER  BY submissions_count ASC
```

**Update:**

Here is the missing information:

I need all row data from Quizzes. I only need the count for ordering within the query (the quizzes with the least amount of submissions first).

```
k-voc_development=# \d quizzes;
                                         Table "public.quizzes"
       Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
    ------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
     id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('quizzes_id_seq'::regclass)
     question   | character varying           | not null
     created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
     updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
    Indexes:
        "quizzes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    Referenced by:
        TABLE "submissions" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_04e433a811" FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizzes(id)
        TABLE "answers" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_431b8a33a3" FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizzes(id)

    k-voc_development=# \d submissions;
                                         Table "public.submissions"
       Column   |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         
    ------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
     id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('submissions_id_seq'::regclass)
     quiz_id    | integer                     | not null
     correct    | boolean                     | not null
     created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
     updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
    Indexes:
        "submissions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
        "index_submissions_on_quiz_id" btree (quiz_id)
    Foreign-key constraints:
        "fk_rails_04e433a811" FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizzes(id)

    k-voc_development=#
```

Comment: Do you need actual row data from `Quizzes`, or is `id` enough? Do you need the count? Count just t/f or *all* rows in `submissions`. Table definitions (`\d tbl` in psql) would clarify data types and constraints and should accompany any such question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the missing info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution depends on the details of your implementation, data distribution and requirements.

**If** you have a typical installation with referential integrity (FK constraint) and defined `submissions.correct` as `boolean NOT NULL` and just want the `quiz_id` along with a count of total submissions, then you don't need to join in `quizzes` at all and this should be fastest:

```
SELECT quiz_id, count(*) AS ct
FROM   submissions
-- WHERE  correct IS NOT NULL -- only relevant if correct can be NULL
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING bool_or(correct)
AND    bool_or(NOT correct);
```

The dedicated [aggregate function `bool_or()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is particularly useful for your test with boolean values. Simpler and faster than a `CASE` expression or similar constructs.

There are *many* other techniques, the best solution depends on the missing information.

#### For your updated requirements

> I need all row data from `quizzes`. I only need the count for ordering
>   within the query (the quizzes with the least amount of submissions first).

This should be fastest if **lots** of quizzes qualify (high percentage of total).

```
SELECT q.*
FROM  (
   SELECT quiz_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   submissions
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) > count(correct OR NULL)
   ) s
JOIN   quizzes q ON q.id = s.quiz_id
ORDER  BY s.ct;
```

`count(*) > count(correct OR NULL)` works because `correct` is `boolean NOT NULL`. Should be slightly faster than the variant above for *few* submissions per quiz.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- I want to fetch all Quizzes
SELECT * FROM quizzes q
WHERE EXISTS ( -- that have at least one associated Submission with submissions.correct = t
    SELECT * FROM submissions s
    WHERE s.quiz_id = q.id AND s.correct = 't'
    )
AND EXISTS ( -- and at least one associated Submission with submissions.correct = f.
    SELECT * FROM submissions s
    WHERE s.quiz_id = q.id AND s.correct = 'f'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other submissions.correct values than t and f, then this will work:

```
SELECT quizzes.*,
       Count(submissions.id) AS submissions_count
FROM   "quizzes"
       INNER JOIN "submissions"
               ON "submissions"."quiz_id" = "quizzes"."id"
GROUP  BY quizzes.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT submissions.correct) >= 2
ORDER  BY submissions_count ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `where` clause to `Having` Clause with `Conditional Count` aggregate

```
SELECT quizzes.*,
       Count(submissions.id) AS submissions_count
FROM   "quizzes"
       INNER JOIN "submissions"
               ON "submissions"."quiz_id" = "quizzes"."id"
GROUP  BY quizzes.id
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN submissions.correct = 'f' THEN 1 END) >= 1
        and Count(CASE WHEN submissions.correct = 't' THEN 1 END) >= 1
ORDER  BY submissions_count ASC
```